What could cause a delayed triggering to a watchpoint?
If we have a watchpoint that is hit when a write operation happens to a particular address.
What could cause a delay between issuing the write operation and triggering the watchpoint.
I guess the watchpoint is triggered at the decode stage of the pipeline. Does it mean that if the pipeline is flushed before the write operation, it might be delayed?
Is the watchpoint actually hit at the write issue time or at the actual write to memory.
I am interested in how this implemented on ARM Cortex M cores.

Many Cortex M have a write buffer.  I know that faults happen late if it is enabled.  Maybe this also happens with watchpoints.  The architecture probably leaves the exact behaviour unspecified, so check the TRM for the specific core you are using.  A simple test would be to disable the write buffer in the Auxiliary Control Register, (ACTLR).
